# Turn on schuffle when click jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

I am trying to make random play, I would like to click a button, then automatically after the film opened up next.

This code works but only when the movie is finish then you have to manually click #schuffle and opens up the next item. I want to only had to click once and then activated by this code every time when the film is completed, that is, return 0.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#schuffle").on('click',function(e) {
                        //ytplayer.getPlayerState() return 0 when video is finish
            //if youtube video is finish
             if ( ytplayer.getPlayerState() == 0 ) {
                //click random element out .koncentrator a.utwor
                var list = $('.koncentrator a.utwor');
                //click random .koncentrator a.utwor
                list.eq(parseInt(Math.random()*list.length)).click();
                //scroll to element
                $(".active").get(0).scrollIntoView();

     }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this? If the user clicks on the button it activates a setInterval with CheckYoutubeVideo() every second.

```
function checkYoutubeVideo()
{
    //ytplayer.getPlayerState() return 0 when video is finish
    //if youtube video is finish
    if ( ytplayer.getPlayerState() == 0 ) {

        //click random element out .koncentrator a.utwor
        var list = $('.koncentrator a.utwor');

        //click random .koncentrator a.utwor
        list.eq(parseInt(Math.random()*list.length)).click();

        //scroll to element
        $(".active").get(0).scrollIntoView();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#schuffle").on('click',function(e) {
        setInterval(checkYoutubeVideo(), 1000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  function playerStateChanged(state) {
      // State code 0 means playback ended
      if(state==0) {
        var list = $('.koncentrator a.utwor');
        list.eq(parseInt(Math.random()*list.length)).click();
        setTimeout(function(){
        $(".active").get(0).scrollIntoView();
        }, 1000);
      }
    }
```

this Working! but how activate this function only when click button, again clicking turn off this function?